# Measuring power draw of more complex loads such as switching PSU

Tags: microcontroller, ac, power-consumption

I'm trying to create an extension cord capable of measuring the power draw of devices connected to it. My approach is using a microcontroller with a non-invasive [HWTC current sensor](https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=SB_20190404124348&SearchText=HWCT-5A%2F5mA). I am using an [ADS1015 12-bit ADC](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1083) which is capable of converting up to 3300 samples per second. The microcontroller is programmed so that it finds the highest voltage peak flowing through the sensor (as I am measuring AC) and then I am calculating the RMS current.

[image: Simple schematics]

This is a simplified code running on my MCU:

```
/// Gets the peak voltage over the next 500 ms
/// \returns Peak voltage in mV
float getPeakVoltage(ADS1015& adc) {
    Int16 maximum = 0;
    const Ulong start = millis();
    // Measure for 500 ms
    while ((millis() - start) < 500) {
        const Int16 value = adc.readDifferential();
        if (value > maximum) {
            maximum = value;
        }
    }
    // 1 bit from ADC = 3mV
    return static_cast<float>(maximum) * 3.0f;
}

const float peakVoltage = getPeakVoltage(adc);
// Using Ohm's law
static constexpr float resistorValue = 220.0;
const float peakCurrent = peakVoltage / resistorValue; // Sensor current ratio is 1000:1
const float powerDrawRms = 230.0 * peakCurrent * 0.707f; // in Watts
```

This approach works flawlessly for simple loads such as a Wolfram light bulb, however, when I connect, for example, a phone charger, it yields garbage. And by garbage, I mean way too high current draw.

Now I, unfortunately, don't have an oscilloscope to see what the waveform looks like, nonetheless, why my approach fails with different loads attached to the sensor?

Comment: _”I, unfortunately, don't have an oscilloscope to see what the waveform looks like”_ That will make it near impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: @winny So you think the general approach is correct? Because I think there must be something wrong with my approach. Something is telling me, it's not gonna be that easy as I thought it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are assuming the current waveform is sinusoidal since you are taking only the peak value and then calculating the RMS value. In practice, since many devices use switching power supplies, the current waveform will not be sunusoidal and may have large peaks.  Since your ADC can sample fast enough, you should take many more samples over one or more cycles of the input current waveform (either 50 or 60 Hz) and calculate the RMS value from them.

Comment: So in other words what you're saying, the solution is to take all the samples into account and instead of calculating RMS, I should integrate the waveform?

Comment: Marking this as the solution as this clearly answers my question. Thanks for getting me on the right track.

Comment: If you are trying to measure power (Not the same thing as current) you also need to be sampling the voltage so that you can integrate VI to get real power (Voltage and current are not necessarily in phase, and the voltage is probably also not a sine wave).

Answer (score 1):

If you change your algorithm to do a simple average to RMS conversion you will see less error.  But, doing true RMS calculations is more accurate but consumes most of the uC time at 3200 samples per second.

Pulse Vpk to Vrms, Vpk/√d at d=5% Vrms=0.22Vp
- but using Vpk/√2=0.707Vp  thus result is 0.707/0.22= **3.2x true rms**
- but using rectified Vavg, \$V_{RMS}=\frac{2}{\pi}V_{AVG}= 0.637 V_{AVG}\$
- then on the same pulse Vavg=Vpk*d=Vrms
- but if using the same conversion the error Vrms=0.637*Vavg
  - your d=5% pulse error is -36.3% instead of +320%

[image]

This is just another approach and not necessarily the best which requires your error assumptions for power factor PF and crest factor (Pk/rms) with measurement error tolerance.

**LPF method**

Another approach is to apply a low pass filter on the rectified current waveform with **-20dB at 4f**. This steep filter is accomplished with an 8th order Butterworth **LPF at 3f** where f is the fundamental line frequency (50 or 60)  This reduces the crest factor of noise pulses but can be implemented in one quad OpAmp with gain. and is 8x better than integration since it is 8th order with only **0.3% attenuation at f** instead of -3dB (-31%).  But then the same filter must be applied to voltage so that power factor angle difference does not change.

Best is a true RMS multiplier function or IC for RMS power.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, but due to a lack of understanding everything you're saying, I will try what Barry is suggesting and if I'll fail with that, I will go with some specialized IC made for this application. In such case, is there some IC you would recommend?

Comment: So as long as you can compute RMS over 1 or more cycles, that's better But you should still use some LPF e.g. -50dB at 1/2 the conversion rate ~1.65kHz otherwise you may get aliasing error

Comment: Do you understand the errors from not having a Nyquist filter?

Comment: You can use your audio channel as a scope, ya know how?

Comment: I hope I do, but I am still lost in how I would compute the attenuation of such low pass filter... You're saying -50dB at ~1.65kHz, that means I could use, for example, a 1k resistor with a 100nF capacitor, right? But how do I determine the attenuation? Just stop me if this is getting out of the boundaries of this question.

Comment: Yes, I've used such a ghetto-oscilloscope in the past!

Comment: Not so primitive now https://www.zeitnitz.eu/scms/images/scope_146_en_small.gif  There are active filter automation tools now free on web,

Comment: Also beware your garbage readings may be resonance or something else. So a scope is essential and compare with a shunt resistor and Diff Amp.

Comment: This may become an XY problem about Pk/RMS and actually a high Q self-resonant frequency problem due to winding capacitance from 1:1k winding ratios for a 5A current sensor. giving you garbage readings on HF noisy chargers. and the garbage which you have yet to define!

Comment: Yes, from what I've read today, I cannot measure switching PSUs with the approach I described in my question. I just found some pictures of the waveform of a switching PSU power draw and it's nowhere near a sinusoidal waveform. Because of what I saw I think I understand the need of the low pass filter - so I'd be able to integrate the waveform with less error. I will give it a try tomorrow, it's 2:30 AM here where I live. Thank you very much for your time and effort, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no clue what a high Q self-resonant frequency means, I am self taught in electronics so I am unaware of such terms...

Comment: I highly recommend this filter software https://filterpro.software.informer.com/download and choose 500 Hz LPF and prefer Salens&Keys type

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I will give it a try once I'm on a Windows machine :-)

Comment: newer version https://www.softpedia.com/get/Science-CAD/FilterPro-Desktop.shtml  There's also a browser version on TI.com site

Comment: Only shame is that it's not available for Linux, but I found some online tools, such as [this one](https://webench.ti.com/filter-design-tool/filter-response) from Texas Instruments.

Comment: that's the browser-based ti.com one.. Filters are defined by gain (1 or more) passband f at -3dB and stop band at -x dB @f then it computes your options such as low Q Bessel or high Q Chebychev  where Q is sort of the resonant gain of slope or a BPF or a resonance. ok nite